# React native IOS build fails in Release at get RCT_METRO_PORT; builds fine in Debug

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native, expo

I have a react native app that I'm able to build and run in a Debug configuration with Metro running on the Mac I'm building from. When I try to run a release target however I get the following error:

```
Error: GetEnv.NoInteger:  is not an integer.
Error: GetEnv.NoInteger:  is not an integer.
    at Object.int (/Users/myusername/code/plates/node_modules/getenv/index.js:38:13)
    at /Users/myusername/code/plates/node_modules/getenv/index.js:84:27
    at get RCT_METRO_PORT [as RCT_METRO_PORT] (/Users/narek/code/plates/node_modules/@expo/metro-config/build/env.js:27:30)
    at getDefaultConfig (/Users/narek/code/plates/node_modules/@expo/metro-config/build/ExpoMetroConfig.js:323:31)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/narek/code/plates/metro.config.js:34:23)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1378:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1437:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1212:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1237:19)
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I've tried a clean build, pod deintegrate etc.
I've also tried setting the RCT_METRO_PORT environment variable, since it seems the failure is in the following line, but this did not help:

node_modules/@expo/metro-config/build/ExpoMetroConfig.js

```
      port: Number(_env2().env.RCT_METRO_PORT) || 8081,
```

Comment: Having the same issue, but building with mode Release